# Fetching Object Size using Instrumentation

Tags: java, instrumentation, objectsize

I have an object which is a composite of several other objects. When i use the getObjectSize() method in the Instrumentation package, does it include the size of the composite objects also?

Answer (score 0):

The API [doc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#getObjectSize%28java.lang.Object%29) says:

> The result may include some or all of the object's overhead, and thus is useful for comparison within an implementation but not between implementations. The estimate may change during a single invocation of the JVM.

Answer (score 0):

No.  The returned size reflects the size of that object - it includes the references that object holds, but not the size of the objects being referred to.  (And, as others have noted, it's not guaranteed to actually be correct.)

Answer (score -1):

`getObjectSize(Object obj)` returns the storage consumed by the specified object (`obj`)... so you will get the size of whatever you will specify.

Comment: Not necessarily. It returns an approximate value of the size, that too dependent on the implementation.